# Activeadmin and Formtastic: form not responding to :size

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, activeadmin

I am trying to format a form and the text fields respond to some methods, and not others.

I can do things like:

```
f.input :name, :input_html => { :maxlength => 10 }
f.input :name, :input_html => { :disabled => true }
```

But if I try to do any of the following, they do not work:

```
f.input :name, :input_html => { :size => 10 }
f.input :name, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow' }
f.input :name, :input_html => { :rows => 10, :cols => 10 }
```

When I try using :size, for instance, the generated html shows that size=10, but is not reflected in the actual form.

These were more or less pulled right from the Formtastic documentation on Github, which the Activeadmin documentation refers to.

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure if your question is solved or not.

However according to Formastic Official WIKI, your code should work:

> Customize HTML attributes for any input using the :input_html option.
>   Typically this is used to disable the input, change the size of a text
>   field, change the rows in a textarea, or even to add a special class
>   to an input to attach special behavior like autogrow textareas:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title,      :input_html => { :size => 10 } %>
    <%= f.input :body,       :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 10, :cols => 20, :maxlength => 10  } %>
    <%= f.input :created_at, :input_html => { :disabled => true } %>
    <%= f.input :updated_at, :input_html => { :readonly => true } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

if your code doesn't work , please check out the error logs, or put more debug info to your erb file, to see if you r rails is running under production mode.

Comment: For me this doesn't work. Rows and class do get to the textarea, but don't do anything.. I'm using Foundation Zurb.

Comment: It didn't work for my case either. I'm using activeadmin with a partial for generating the form

Comment: active admin is evil...let's forget it... ^_^

Comment: ActiveAdmin is good for very simple projects because not for huge projects that require a great deal of customization. So much re-learning and depending on their poor documentation makes it extremely frustrating to work with.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem. i wanted a nested form for edit with custom text field size.this worked for me.

```
    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Header" do
        cf.input :name, :input_html => { :class => 'some_style', :rows => 2, :style => 'width:50%'}
      end
      f.actions
    end
```

so basically u have to create your own class or just work with the :style.

For nested form u can use this code

```
    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Header" do
        f.has_many :name,:allow_destroy => true,:new_record => true do |cf|
          cf.input :first_name, :input_html => { :class => 'some_style', :rows => 2, :style => 'width:50%'}
        end
      end
      f.actions
    end
```